# A homework question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I came across a question which goes as follows:-

Let $S$ be a set defined as follows:- $S=\{(x,y)|(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}{\times} \mathbb{R} $ where $x\notin \mathbb{Z}$ and $y\notin \mathbb{Q}\}.$ Now, my question goes as follows:-

Can $S$ be also written as $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: If by $\Bbb R\over \Bbb Z$, you mean $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z=\{ x|x\in\Bbb R \text{ and }x\notin\Bbb Z\}$, then yes.

Comment: @ David Mitra, yep, that's what I meant. anyways thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If by $\Bbb R\over \Bbb Z$, you mean $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z=\{ x|x\in\Bbb R \text{ and }x\notin\Bbb Z\}$ (and similarly for $\Bbb R\over \Bbb Q$), then yes.

This is just the definition of Cartesion product:
$$
A\times B=\{\,(a,b)\,|\, a\in A, b\in B\,\}
$$

So
$$
(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z) \times (\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)
=\bigl\{\,(x,y)\,|\, x\in \Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z, y\in \Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\,\bigr\}
=\bigl\{\,(x,y)\,|\, x,y \in \Bbb R, x\notin\Bbb Z, y\notin \Bbb Q\,\bigr\}.
$$